# Accept payments in Electron application with Stripe

Tags: node.js, electron, stripe-payments

I'm trying to accept billing subscription using the **Stripe API** in my **Electron** app. I would create an endpoint in the 'main' file but I guess it's insecure and not the right place to do that.

What's the most secure payment flow in **Electron** apps? Would I need to do this using a simple web page and a **nodeJs** server?

Answer (score 1):

You must not include your secret key in any client application. Your Electron client needs to make calls to your remote server where you can make secret key API calls securely.

Yes, if you want to build a server in the JS/Node ecosystem, you can use Stripe's `stripe-node` client and build a server like [this example](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/master/fixed-price-subscriptions/server/node/server.js).